# Ignored traits specialization in c++

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, traits

I have some hard time implementing traits in C++, I tried to follow several examples from the internet but it still doesn't want to compile.

I use a `Term` class, which contains an `Attribute`, an `Operator` and sometimes a value. For example, `age < 10` or `color == red` are (simple) terms. Different kinds of attributes or operators exists, that inherits from classes `Attribute` or `TermOperator`.
Since a lot of methods of the `term` class will depend on the attribute and the operator, this is a template class. In order to simplify the manipulation of terms, I added an abstract class : `AbstractTerm`

```
class AbstractTerm {
protected:
    Attribute* pAttribute;
    TermOperator* pOperator;
public:
    virtual bool eval(Data *) const = 0;
};

template <typename ATT, typename OP>
class Term : AbstractTerm {
    typedef typename TermTraits<ATT,OP>::type  VALUE_TYPE;
private:
    typename TermTraits<ATT,OP>::type value;
public:
    bool eval(Data *) const;
};
```

The value I need to store in `term` will depend on both attribute & operator, so I use traits to obtain the right type to store the value.

```
template < typename ATT, typename OP>
struct TermTraits
{
    typedef int type;       
};

template <>
struct TermTraits<ListAttribute, TermOperator>
{
    typedef ListValue type;
};

template <>
struct TermTraits<NumericAttribute, TermOperator>
{
    typedef NumericIntValue type;
};
```

However, in the `eval` method when I use `VALUE_TYPE` I don't get the right type

```
template <> bool Term<NumericAttribute, TermOperatorEquals>::eval(Data _data) const {
    // VALUE_TYPE is a int, but it should be a NumericIntValue
    VALUE_TYPE *pValue = data->getValue<VALUE_TYPE>(this->pAttribute->getId());
    return !pValue->isEmpty && (this->value == pValue->value); // I get compilation errors here because pValue is a int* and not a 'NumericIntValue*'
};
```

I get the error:

```
error: request for member 'isEmpty' in '* pValue', 
which is of non-class type 'Term<NumericAttribute, 
TermOperatorExists>::VALUE_TYPE {aka int}.
```

I can't figure out why it doesn't use the specialisation `TermTraits<NumericAttribute, TermOperator>`, since `TermOperatorExists` inherits from `TermOperator`.

Traits are a new concept to me, so maybe I made some obvious mistakes. If someone has a better way or simpler way to do this I'm also interested.

Comment: Independent from your error, you probably want to inherit publicly from ``AbstractTerm`` and also mark ``bool eval(Data *) const`` with ``override``, to make sure that it actually overrides (compiler will complain if it cannot override).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `TermOperatorExists` inherits from `TermOperator`, those are different types, so template specialization is not called for `TermOperatorExists`. You need to explicitly cast `TermOperatorExists` to its base class in order to get specialization called.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base
{
};
class derrived: public base
{
};

class test
{
    public:
    template <class T> void print(T arg)
    {
        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <>
void test::print<base>(base arg)
{
    std::cout << "base specialiation" << std::endl;
};

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
   base b;
   derrived d;


   test t;
    t.print<int>(1);
    t.print(b);
    t.print(d);
    t.print(static_cast<base>(d));
   return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
Hello World
test
base specialiation
test
base specialiation
```